Variable buffer at defined z slope to DEM in QGIS
I am trying to introduce some basic grading tools to my QGIS workflow that would otherwise have to be done in Civil3D by another person.
The basic idea is to take a polygon and buffer its vertices at a specific slope (say 3:1) such that the final buffer distance is defined by the intersection with the slope and a DEM.
I have not found any plugin for this purpose. What might be possible in a custom model? Maybe this is actually a plug-in development project?
